# Change machine delay time for rejected source in AnyLogic

Tags: simulation, anylogic

Agent moving from **machine block (machine block delay is 9 minutes) to milling block**. At the milling block, 7 percent gets rejected and goes back to the machine block.
Now rejected agents move from machine to milling block, but this time the machine block delay time is 12 minutes. **The question is, how can I achieve this 12 minute delay time now?**

*** The logic image is given below:***
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the agent type of of your agents going through the process, create a variable of type boolean and call it `rejected` with initial value `false`. ***On Exit (false)*** of the your ***selectOutput1*** write:

```
agent.rejected = true
```

The delay of the machine block should be

```
agent.rejected ? 12 : 9
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. Now, how do I show the total number of times that the components are rejected?

Comment: Create a variable and on exit false write variable++